# how to build a get_absolute_url with year, month, day and slug on Djano Rest Framework

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework

I'm building a blog aplication with DRF, and I want it to be able to get my get_absolute_url method for each post, like: http://127.0.0.1:8001/blog/posts/2022/10/11/my-post
And not the default: http://127.0.0.1:8001/blog/posts/1

Here's my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'), ('published', 'Published')
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='publish', max_length=250)
body = models.TextField()

author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')

publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="posts" ,blank=True, null=True )

objects = models.Manager()
published = PublishedManager()

tags = TaggableManager()

feature_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/", null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.publish.year,
                                             self.publish.month,
                                             self.publish.day,
                                             self.slug], )
```

And my serializer:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['url', 'id', 'title', 'slug', 'body', 'author', 'publish', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    'status', 'category', 'feature_image']
```

Somebody help how to do that, please.
thanks!

Edit:

This is the error that I get when running the app:
NoReverseMatch at /blog/posts/
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(2022, 10, 11, 'first-post-2')' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/posts/(?P[^/.]+)\.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'blog/posts/(?P[^/.]+)/$']

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted and what I've seen you don't seem to be doing anything wrong.
Could you describe what **that** spits out?- is it crashing?- is the url wrong?- does it need the website prefix?

I've also seen this, /, which might be a route you could take. (I've done this with custom admin pages)

```py
class BlogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_url(self, obj):
    return obj.get_absolute_url()

  class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['url', 'id', 'title', 'slug', 'body', 'author', 'publish', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    'status', 'category', 'feature_image']
```

---

#### Edit

Yeah, that looks like a problem with your Urls. the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#example) show this:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
  path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
  path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
  path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
]
```

So your path might end up like:

- **Note:** Idk what that last one is supposed to be, I just put title.. you use `slug` for any string, if you end up doing a pk instead use `int`

```py
urlpatterns = [
  path('posts/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:title>/', views.post_detail),
]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

NoReverseMatch at /blog/posts/
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(2022, 10, 11, 'first-post-2')' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/posts/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'blog/posts/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']

Comment: May the problem be in my urls?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Yeah, that a URLs problem. I've added what I'd generally do after looking at the Docs